# Can't find Firefox Redux Dev Tools in the store

Tags: redux-toolkit

I've been trying to enable the Firefox Redux Dev Tools but it can't find the store.

So I'm using Expo (Metro Bundler running on http://localhost:19002/), I have enabled 'Debug Remotely' on the iOS simulator, which opened a new tab in Firefox (http://localhost:19000/debugger-ui/ - React Native Debugger). If I open the dev tools on that tab and go to the Redux tab, I get the message that no store has been found. The documentation seems to be for 'traditional' setup, no Redux toolkit.

My store is as follows. Although the Redux Toolkit says that devTools option is enabled by default, I've added it as well (doesn't work if I omit this option either)

```
export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    tasks: tasksReducer
  },
  devTools: true
});
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem there seems to be no real guide for setting up redux devtools with the new toolkit and expo I'm getting an Invariant error which does not show when I run the app without the devtools attached Do you have any sources where one can maybe find some info on how to set this up properly? I installed the latest version of the React Native Debugger, changed the port to 19000 and added the devTools property you showed above but to no avail

Answer (score 0):

It was a question of changing:

```
devTools: true
```

to:

```
  devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
```